# Close child window, redirect parent window

Tags: javascript, redirect, window

I've got a page which opens a child window, from a parent.

After the user has done something in the child window, I need the child window to close, and its parent window to be redirected to a page, on the click of a button in the child window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

from child:

```
opener.location.href = '/redirect';
close();
```

Comment: but IE shows popup blocked :( Any solution working in IE too?

Comment: @Binod -- IE blocking a popup has nothing to do with this question.  Please ask a new question if you are having issues, this one is almost 3 years old.

Comment: The problem was Same origin policy. If the windows are not of the same origin, then IE considers this redirect as a popup

Answer (score 20):

The key is to use `window.opener` to access the parent window:

```
<script>
    window.opener.location = '/redirect.html';
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: you want to flip those lines, think about it :)

Comment: @cwolves: It works either way. You can still access the properties of the window object even after it's closed.

Comment: That's not guaranteed.  Granted, it will probably always work in this scenario, but the browser will start to tear down the window and will eventually kill JS execution mid-statement.  If you had long-running code after `window.close()`, there's a chance it wouldn't finish.  There's also a chance that some browser will say "no code allowed to run after `window.close()`" and just kill it immediately

Comment: @cwolves - Good point that we don't know what a browser might do, so safer to just do it in the logical order. I flipped the two lines in my answer.

Comment: The only reason I really point this out is that I've run into a scenario where I ran a lot of logic in `window.onbeforeunload` and the browser killed it :(

Comment: This was working perfectly for a long time but suddenly window.opener is null in both Chrome and Firefox for any popup window I open. :(

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var parent = window.opener;

parent.location ='some url';

window.close();
```

here is an example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/jGbZq/

Answer (score 2):

Please try below :

```
window.opener.location.reload();
close();
```

1. window.opener.location.reload(); will reload the parent window.
2. close() will close the child window

It works fine for me.