# JavaScript: Redirecting after closing an alert that came from a popup of another window

Tags: javascript

The situation is that the site I am working on will display a popup after 10 minutes of inactivity, then 5 minutes (which is counted down in the popup window) an alert message appears informing the user has been logged out.

I am trying to redirect the original page to the page that will done an abandon and redirect to the logon page, but I am struggling to succeed at this;

```js
 window.opener.opener.replace("relevantPage.aspx");
 window.close;
```

All in the relevant tags by the way. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Also, your code snippet does nothing. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'opener' of null `

Comment: Sorry don't how Java got in there, when I was researching into different ways to accomplish the redirect the .opener part was suggested:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656349/close-child-window-redirect-parent-window

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code for execution after 10 minutes of inactivity will look like this:

```
showPopup(.....);
// on ready popup action
function onReadyPopup(){
  //redirect to "/your page" after 5 minutes
  window.setTimeout(function(){ window.location="/your page"; },5*60*1000);
  //every second update counter in popup
  window.setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
}
```