# Redirecting back 2 pages and reloading that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a login page in a new tool and after logging in to it, I am forced to redirect to a specific page(fixed path). I want to make it dynamic and redirect to the page that the user came from. TO do  this, I am making the forced redirected page blank, and writing the below JS code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.setTimeout('redirect()',3000);
 function redirect(){
 window.history.go(-2);
 }
 </script>
```

This code works fine and does takes me to the page from where am landing to the login page, but the problem is the referrer page is not getting reloaded and updated with the logged-in username - but it does happen if I manually reload the page. How can I reload the page so the username appears?

`document.referrer` will not work for me as I need to redirect to -2 page, not the immediate back page.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle it from your web framework, such that if any request comes to that page then use the redirect method from your framework to show desired page.

Also

Since you are using `history` method that's why you get the cached result. You should use something like:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

or

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Also see: [Close child window, redirect parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656349/close-child-window-redirect-parent-window)

Comment: The tool does not give me access to make any server side coding to handle it from web framework.I have to handle it using java script/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To go to a particular page after the login is successful, the easiest way is to pass the required page URL as a GET parameter to the login page:

```
yoursite.org/login?next=/page/they/came/from
```

then redirect the user to `/page/they/came/from` if the login is successful (i.e. return a server side 302 redirect). This is how Django does it.