# How to redirect in HTML, JS, if user closes "window.open()" - Dialog?

Tags: javascript, html

The user clicks on `Download` on my homepage and I call `window.open(..)`. 
If the users presses on `OK` or `Cancel`, I want to redirect the window!

How is this possible?

Here's my example:
[A Download-Link of my Homepage](http://guger.bplaced.net/php/download.php?ui=false&plf=android&prg=musixs)

You open the page, the dialog appears, you click on `Ok` or `Cancel` and then the window should redirect!

Comment: In "OK" use an onclick event and call a function in that event containing window.location and if 'Cancel' is clicked use 'window.close()'

Comment: how could i add an OK-onClick-Event to an Standart window.open-Dialog??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close child window, redirect parent window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656349/close-child-window-redirect-parent-window)

Comment: Where are the OK and Cancel buttons: in the parent window, or in the window opened by `window.open`?   Which window do you want to redirect?

Comment: The buttons are in the window.open dialog and i want to redirect the parent window

Answer (score 0):

If OK and Cancel reside in the  new created window and the redirect shall redirect this new window use `window.location ='http://....'`

If Ok and Cancel reside in the main window and the redirect shall redirect the new window use `myWin=window.open();  myWin.location='http://...'`

If Ok and Cancel reside in the new window and redirect shall redirect the main window, you will have to get access from the new window to the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Window

```
<script language="Javascript">

    function fbLoginWindow(){
        url = "fbLogin.html"
        newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    }

</script>
```

```
<input type="button" OnClick="fbLoginWindow()" value="Login FB" />
```

Child Window --- **fbLogin.html**

```
<script language="Javascript">

    function fbProfile(){
        window.opener.location.href="http://wwww.facebook.com";
        self.close();
    }

</script>
```

```
Allow the user to view FB Profile
<br/>Are you sure?
<input type="button" value="Ok" OnClick="fbProfile()" />
```